# how to select strings in sql order by shortest strings or most relevancy from the first character

Tags: sql, mysql

i have a query in my php which is as follow :

```
$query = "
    SELECT ydzdn_terms.term_id,ydzdn_terms.name 
      FROM ydzdn_terms 
INNER JOIN ydzdn_term_taxonomy on 
               (ydzdn_terms.term_id=ydzdn_term_taxonomy.term_id ) 
     WHERE ydzdn_term_taxonomy.taxonomy='location' 
       AND ydzdn_terms.name like '%" . $_GET["keyword"] . "%' 
  ORDER BY ydzdn_terms.name ASC 
     LIMIT 0,5";
```

it outputs result based on what user types and matches are anywhere in text and as we can show only up to 5 results. the most importent results that are always short in string lengh would be hidden.
to be more clear our database is about locations and street names containing cities and states like :
south main street, wake forest, NC

but we have also city name itself like: wakeforest, NC

and i want it to be seen at top of the list when someone types : wake forest

i need this sql to be the way that outputs the shortest strings first or orders results based on most relevancy from the first character

Comment: If somebody types `wake forest` (with a space) then it will not match `wakeforest, NC` (without a space), unless you do some kind of fuzzy matching.

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32391315)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Please try the below query (untested).

```
$query = "
SELECT ydzdn_terms.term_id, ydzdn_terms.name 
FROM ydzdn_terms 
INNER JOIN ydzdn_term_taxonomy ON (ydzdn_terms.term_id = ydzdn_term_taxonomy.term_id) 
WHERE ydzdn_term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'location' 
AND ydzdn_terms.name LIKE '%" . $_GET["keyword"] . "%' 
ORDER BY 
    LOCATE('" . $_GET["keyword"] . "', ydzdn_terms.name), 
    LENGTH(ydzdn_terms.name) ASC 
LIMIT 0, 5";
```

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32391315)